# WordPress обратная форма

Tags: wordpress, form, design, contact-form7

С попощью какого плагина можно реализовать эту форму на WordPress. Очень понравилась на [этом сайте](https://atom-media.ru) Думал попробывать Contact form7 но не уверен что он справится и имеет такую кастомизацию.Вот её скрин[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Смог её внешний вид реализовать на html, но вот вспомнил что есть такое как плагины..И какой выбрать не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте Contact Form 7 и стилизуйте полученную форму с помощью css.

Я не вижу никаких моментов на этой картинке, которые нельзя было бы реализовать таким способом.

Comment: Ок, значит попробуем

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.